# Derivations for Context Free Grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar, computer-science-theory, chomsky-normal-form

Ultimately I want to convert the following CFG into Chomsky Normal Form:

```
S→aSbS∣bSaS∣ε
```

However, I'm not sure if I'm doing the derivations correctly--here is what I have:

Replacing nonterminals with terminals

```
S→aabb

S→ε
```

Could someone tell me if this is correct/on the right track?

Thank you.

Comment: More combinations are possible than those which you have listed.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form

Comment: @Ashalynd Is this right ?
 A-> a
 B-> b
 C-> AS
 D-> BS
 S-> CD|DC|ε

Comment: No. Chomsky normal form means no epsilon, and no complex statements.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ashalynd wrote, you should read a bit [more about Chomsky Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form):

> Chomsky normal form means no epsilon, and no complex statements.

The grammar you have contains an ε and therefore can never be transformed into a CNF as ε is a valid sentence in the language produced by `S.`